# app-header doesn't hide Polymer 2.0

Tags: javascript, polymer, polymer-2.x

I've got a problem since I migrate to Polymer 2.0, my `app-header` doesn't want to hide but for exemple `app-drawer` does with the same attribute value. Here is my code:

```
<app-header slot="header" fixed shadow effects="waterfall" hidden$=[[!storedUser.loggedin]]>
    <app-toolbar>
        <div class="header--menu header--menu__size">
            <paper-button drawer-toggle>
                <iron-icon icon="menu" drawer-toggle></iron-icon>
            </paper-button>
        </div>
        <div class="header--title" main-title>Test</div>
        <div class="header--setting header--setting__size">
            <paper-button on-tap="_logout">
                <custom-icon iconset="ci-login" icon="normal"></custom-icon>
                <span>[ [[localize('logout')]] ]</span>
            </paper-button>
        </div>
    </app-toolbar>
</app-header>
```

If you want more info / code don't hesitate.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Remove the property `fixed` from `app-header`.

Check the documentation for all available properties [app-header](https://www.webcomponents.org/element/PolymerElements/app-layout/v2.1.0/elements/app-header)